# Youtube api -how to return nextpage token from fuction?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

Using youtube api to get playlist items. There are more than 50 in the list so will need to build a loop to get them. When a button is clicked I'm calling a function that will return 50 at a time then will build a loop to get all items.

Having problems returning the nextpagetoken from the function. I couldn't figure out a way to return the data so got to a point where I've just plugged the nextpagetoken into the html of a div inside the function but, once the function finishes when I try to get the html value it returns blank.

The console.log('Nextpagetoken: ' + data.nextPageToken); command shows the correct value.

The console.log('After call: ' + next); command shows a blank value.

Also, the 'After call' command appears in the console log before the 'Nextpagetoken' log.

Any help greatly received. Here's the javascript and html:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var loop=0;
    var data;
    var next='';

$('#get').click(function(){
    getVids();
    next=$('#pagetoken').text(); 
    console.log('After call: ' + next);
});        

  function getVids(page){
    $('#results').html("");
    data = {
              part: 'snippet',
              maxResults: 50,
              playlistId: 'playlist',
              key: 'myKey',
              pageToken: page
            };
    $.get(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems", data,
      function(data){
        var output;
        console.log('Page: ' + data.nextPageToken);
        $.each(data.items, function(i, item)
            {
              console.log(item);
              videoTitle = item.snippet.title;
              rvideoID = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
              vidThumburl = item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url;
              output = '<li style="list-style:none;">' + rvideoID + ' <a class="videos2 video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + rvideoID + '">' + videoTitle + '<a/></li>';
              //Append to results list
              $('#results').append(output);
            });
        console.log('Nextpagetoken: ' + data.nextPageToken);
        $('#pagetoken').html(data.nextPageToken);

      });       
  }

  });
```

Here's the html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">   
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="yt.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
 <button id='get' type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Go</button>     
      <ul id="results"></ul>
      <div id='pagetoken'></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Next is blank because getVids is async and the html isn't yet appended when you call console.log